# Get the last element of a vector and push it to the same vector

Tags: vector, rust

What I am trying to do:

```
enum Test {
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

fn main() {
    let mut test_vec: Vec<Test> = Vec::new();
    test_vec.push(Test::Value2);

    if let Some(last) = test_vec.last() {
        test_vec.push(*last);
    }
    //Wanted output: vector with [Test::Value2, Test::Value2]
}
```

I understand that when I call `last()`, it will return `Option<&Test>`
So it will borrow the `test_vec` till the end of the if-let block.

I tried the following without success:

```
if let Some(last) = test_vec.last().map(|v| v.clone()) {
    test_vec.push(*last);
}

//and

let last = test_vec.last().unwrap().clone();
test_vec.push(*last);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When trying to figure out why the borrow checker complains it can be useful to identify the types involved.

If you type out:

```
let _: () = test_vec.last().map(|v| v.clone());
```

you get an error complaining that `()` and `core::option::Option<&Test>` are not the same type.

What's going on? Very simply put, if you clone an `&Test` you get an `&Test`, thus calling `.map(|v| v.clone())` on a `Option<&Test>` gives an `Option<&Test>`. Obviously, it still borrows.

The same problem occurs with your next attempt, if you type out:

```
let _: () = test_vec.last().unwrap().clone();
```

you get an error complaining that `()` and `&Test` are not the same type.

By calling `unwrap` on an `Option<&Test>` you get an `&Test` which is then cloned into an `&Test`.

---

So, the problem is a lack of *dereferencing*. You need to dereference earlier, to avoid borrowing `test_vec` in `Some(last)`:

```
if let Some(last) = test_vec.last().map(|v| (*v).clone()) {
    test_vec.push(last);
}
```

of course, this does not work because `Test` does not implement `clone`. Once that is fixed (by `#[derive(Clone)]`), it compiles.

Since cloning from references is such a common need, there is a dedicated method on [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned) (and [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned)) called `cloned`:

```
if let Some(last) = test_vec.last().cloned() {
    test_vec.push(last);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To solve the borrow problem you can call [`Option::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned), that produces a `Option<T>` from a `Option<&T>`. To do this, `Test` must implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/clone/trait.Clone.html). You can implement `Clone` for `Test` using `derive`:

```
// To allow assert_eq, we also derive Debug and PartialEq
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
enum Test {
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

fn main() {
    let mut test_vec = Vec::new();
    test_vec.push(Test::Value2);

    if let Some(last) = test_vec.last().cloned() {
        test_vec.push(last);
    }

    assert_eq!(vec![Test::Value2, Test::Value2], test_vec);
}
```