# How to convert Option<&T> to Option<T> in the most idiomatic way in Rust?

Tags: reference, rust, ownership

When using HashMap's `get` method, I get an `Option<&T>`, I've encountered it again this time with `Option<&String>`. I'd like to get an owned value `Option<String>`. Is this possible without me writing `map(|x| x.to_owned())`?

I'm just wondering if there's a way to write a blanket implementation for any of the utility traits to achieve that?

Comment: You can also write `map(ToOwned::to_owned)`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Option` comes with utility methods for various transformations, which are listed in [its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). For any `T` that implements `Clone` (which `String` does), [`Option<&T>::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned) does what you're looking for.

`Clone` is more specific than `ToOwned`, so `.cloned()` isn't an *exact* match for `.map(|x| x.to_owned())`. For example, it won't turn an `Option<&str>` into an `Option<String>`; for that you will have to stick with `map`.

Since Rust 1.35, when `T` is `Copy`, [`.copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) does the same thing as `.cloned()`, but it will fail to compile when `T` is not `Copy`. You might use this when you want to be explicit that the clone is cheap.

---

See also:

- [How to clone last element from vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907887/how-to-clone-last-element-from-vector)
- [Get the last element of a vector and push it to the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579949/get-the-last-element-of-a-vector-and-push-it-to-the-same-vector)