# How do I convert Option<&T> to Option<T>?

Tags: rust

I don't know how convert `Option<&T>` to `Option<T>`. I'm using the reqwest crate. This is my code:

```
let body: Option<Body> = request.body();
```

But I get `mismatched type` error. How do I convert `Option<&Body>` to `<Option<Body>>`?

Comment: your question doesn't contain a [mcve], we can't answer you, but generally try to [`cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned)

Comment: The question is why you want a `Option<Body>` at all? This seems either be a misunderstanding of ownership or a XY-Problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Option<&T> to Option<T> in the most idiomatic way in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338579/how-to-convert-optiont-to-optiont-in-the-most-idiomatic-way-in-rust)

Answer (score 2):

When you have an `Option<&T>`, you don't actually have the *object* itself. You have, maybe, a reference to the said object. Obviously, you cannot go from "a reference" to "a full-fledged owned object" without some trickery in between. You only currently have a **pointer** to the object, not the object itself, and as such, your only recourse is to find a way to make a copy of it.

If `T` implements `Clone`, you could in theory `clone()` your object and call it a day - this would turn your `Option<&T>` into `Option<T>` at the cost of a full memory copy. Judging by the type signature, this is probably a `hyper` question, however, and `Body` does not implement such a trait.

All other solutions will fail:

- You cannot create a method on the object to destructure it and return `self`, as that would invalidate the borrow you have on `&T`
- You have no way to turn directly from `&T` to `T` as you only have a borrow