# Print last element of vector

Tags: rust

In Rust, I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579949/get-the-last-element-of-a-vector-and-push-it-to-the-same-vector) that we can use the `.last()` function to access the last element of a vector. However, when I try to interpolate this into print output like so

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    v.push(1.0); v.push(1.9); v.push(1.2);
    println!("Last element is {}", v.last());    // (*)
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: `Option<&f64>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
```

The full error text hints that I can use `{:?}` instead. If I change `(*)` to read `println!("Last element is {:?}", v.last());    // (*)`, then the program prints

```
Last element is Some(1.2)
```

How can I just get `Last element is 1.2`?

How can I extract the value `1.2` as an `f64`?

Comment: If you know for sure there's at least 1 element, then just `v.last().unwrap()`. But if there are no items, the program will crash

Comment: Aha, so would it be correct to think of the `Option<&f64>` type (that `last()` returns) as a union type that can contain either the float or a token saying that the vector is empty?

Comment: Yes, except that it doesn't technically store a float `f64`, but a reference to float inside the vector `&f64`

Answer (score 7):

There may or may not be a last element, depending if the Vector is empty or not.

You can check if the `Option<f64>` returned by `last()` is `Some(val)`. This can be done using `if let` or `match` or other techniques (`unwrap()`, `unwrap_or()` etc.). For example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1.0, 1.9, 1.2];
    if let Some(val) = v.last() { 
        println!("Last element is {}", val);
    } else {
        println!("The vector is empty");
    }
}
```